# Twig AND operator with equals

Tags: php, symfony, twig

In my Symofny project on twig view I am displaying button for entities that have specific statuses.

If I define just for one type of status it works, but when I try with two it does not. But it works for to if I put for example '  `!=` '.

```
{% if (item.status == 'free') and (item.status == 'paid') %}

     <a type="button" href="{{ path('my_path', {'id':item.id}) }}" class="btn btn-primary">Btn</a>

  {% endif %}
```

Tried also with `same as` as it's described in twig documentation.

Comment: How can `item.status` be both free and paid?

Comment: I have 5 statuses and I want button to generate something that is related to both free and paid. @NigelRen

Comment: So you mean it's free OR paid?

Comment: Aaaah ... Confusion. :D Now it works. Thanks man. @NigelRen

Answer (score 6):

Another way to solve this is to use an array and the `in` operator

```html
{% if item.status in [ 'free', 'paid', ] %}

{% endif %}
```

Comment: Great to know. Thanks. @DarkBee